# IRA conversion when part of the contributions were non-deductible. Taxes owed?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira, roth-ira, form-8606

I have a traditional IRA, which has money which has been contributed three different ways:

1. deductible IRA contributions
2. non-deductible IRA contributions
3. rollover from 401(k)

I'm looking at converting this to a Roth IRA in 2010, now that there's no income limitation.  I also may only convert part of my traditional IRA this year, to avoid a bump in the marginal tax rate.

I also have a Roth 401(k), although I don't think this has any effect.

How would the calculations work for how much tax I would owe?  Are there any other things I should be aware of?

Comment: OK, so you have a Traditional IRA, a Roth IRA, and a 401(k).  Which are you wanting to move funds out of, and which are you wanting to move funds into?

Comment: @Benjamin Chambers Converting from the Traditional IRA to a Roth IRA.  As far as I know, there's no other type of allowable conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversions are done on a pro-rata basis.  If you haven't yet paid tax on the money, you need to do so in the process of converting.

Let's say you have a total of $50k in your account:

- $10k in deductible contributions
- $10k in non-deductible contributions
- $20k in 401(k) rollover funds
- $10k in as-yet untaxed earnings

If you decide to convert half of this to a Roth ($25k), you'd owe tax on $20k of that, because 80% of your holdings in the traditional IRA have not been taxed yet.  The non-deductible contributions have been taxed, so you don't need to pay tax again on that part.

More information is [here](http://www.money-zine.com/Financial-Planning/Retirement/2010-Roth-IRA-Conversions/).

Answer (score 1):

MB's math is right, but I can describe it in a short sentence.
All Traditional accounts are combined, 401(k) rollover is no different from other IRA money.
You should have been tracking your non-deducted money via [form 8606](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8606.pdf) so you know this figure. The non-deducted money as a percent of your total balance is the percent of conversion that's not taxed. 
(To be clear, deducted contributions and growth are not tracked separately, one only tracks the non-deducted deposits.)